# KeyError: "None of [Index([''], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python

I am trying to implement my first anomaly detection with IsolationForest, but unfortunately it does not succeed.

I have a `.csv` file with different network parameters like ip.ttl, frame.len, etc.

```
#Einlesen
quelle = pd.read_csv('./x.csv')
pdf=quelle.to_numpy()
print(quelle.columns)
```

Index([';ip.proto;ttl;frame.len;ip.src;ip.dst;ip.len;ip.flags;eth.src;eth.dst;eth.type;vlan.id;udp.port'], dtype='object')

```
print(quelle.shape)
```

(1658, 1)

But when I try to create the IsolationForest model with a column like ip.ttl or frame.len (one of the columns), I get an error

```
model=IsolationForest(n_estimators=50, max_samples='auto',contamination=float(0.1),max_features=1.0)
model.fit(quelle[['frame.len']])
```

KeyError: "None of [Index(['frame.len'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your df?

Comment: first lines of the csv
 1;17    1;64 64;148;10.0.0.134 10.0.0.3;10.0.0.135 10.0.0.2;134 84;0x00004000 0x00004000;00:0c:29:a0:b9:8a 00:00:00:00:11:11;00:0c:29:2b:53:ae 00:00:22:22:22:22;0x00000800 0x00000800;;45286                                                4789.0                                              
2;17    1;64 64;148;10.0.0.134 10.0.0.3;10.0.0.135 10.0.0.2;134 84;0x00004000 0x00004000;00:0c:29:a0:b9:8a 00:00:00:00:11:11;00:0c:29:2b:53:ae 00:00:22:22:22:22;0x00000800 0x00000800;;45286                                                4789.0
some information about network packets

Comment: `;` looks to be the delimiter. Can you try: `quelle = pd.read_csv('./x.csv', sep=';')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataframe has many datapoints but only a single column.

```
print(quelle.shape)
(1658, 1)
```

When you loaded the file into the dataframe it failed to auto detect what is the proper delimiter of the file and instead of reading each column, it packed all columns into a single column.

To solve this issue, you should specify delimiter when reading the file.

```
pd.read_csv('./x.csv', sep=';')
```